# jQuery post within post done function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, events

I'm trying to implement and figure out something that I've never done before. I have a sense how to do it but I'm not exactly sure how to do so...

So I have a button on my website where users perform authorization of my application. When user goes to xx website and authorizes my application I would like to perform a jQuery  post to this xx website every 3 seconds checking whether the user has performed authorization of my app to use it.

If the response from the website is success i'd like to make the button enabled and clickable to proceed to final step to insert some record into the DB.

So the current code looks like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btnClick", function (e) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("/GetMyData/GenerateSession")
            .done(function (sessionID) {
                window.open("https://example.com/Authorize?=" + data, "_blank");
                $('#btnClick').hide();
                $('#btnAuthorize').show();
                $("#step2").removeClass("disabled").addClass("selected");
            });
        });
```

So as you can see when SessionID is generated in my aciton, I simply open up a new tab in my browser and take him to the corresponding website.

Now what I'd like to do in final step is remove this code where user himself has to click the button to authorize the application like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnAuthorize", function () {
        $.post('/GetMyData/StoreToken')
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data.result == "Success") {
               window.location.href = '/Success';
        }
    });
    });
```

So without having the user to perform this final step. I'd like to make my application do this for user and perform a post every 3 seconds once he #btnClick even has been triggered..

How could I do this with jQuery?

P.S. I'd like to do this because I've noticed that some people simply don't authorize the application for usage but still press this button ,and then errors occur, which is why I'd like to disable usre clicking this button unless he indeed authorized the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
var r = window.setInterval(function(){
$.post('/GetMyData/StoreToken')
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data.result == "Success") {
           window.location.href = '/Success';
    }
});
},3000);
```

Comment: Yes this is it. Yay !! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform some function every X time you have to use setTimeout/setInterval functions of javascript (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)